# Cherry Framework 4 - Change footer bootstrap settings

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a WordPress website which uses the Cherry Framework 4 and I wonder how this theme works.

In the footer I see this:

```
<footer id="footer" class="site-footer wide" role="contentinfo">
    <div id="static-area-footer-top" class="footer-top static-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 static-footer-menu"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 static-footer-logo"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="static-area-footer-bottom" class="footer-bottom static-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 static-footer-info"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

How can I change the settings, so that `col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5` is changed? I want to have it centered all of the width with col-xs-12?

Anybody knows that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create child theme to modify footer.

Here is [link](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/wordpress-how-to-create-a-child-theme-based-on-cherry-framework.html) to create child theme.after that just copy footer.php from parent theme to child theme.